# In the following modelform how can i access currentuser detail in queryset mentioned in program "CURRENT USER EMAIL ID"

Tags: django

**modelform**

```
class Build_kbform(ModelForm):   
  share_with=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter
  (id__in=S etupuser.share_KB_with.through.objects.values_list
  ("user_id").filter(setupuser_id=Setupuser.objects.values_list
  ("id",flat=True).filter(email_id="CURRENT USER EMAIL ID")[0])) 
  ,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)knowledge = forms.Textarea()
 class Meta:
    model=Buildkb
    exclude=["email"]
```

**formview**

```
class Build_Kb(FormView):
  template_name = "pkm_templates/buildkb.html"
  form_class = Build_kbform
  success_url = '/thanks/'
  def form_valid(self, form):
    share_with=form.cleaned_data.get("share_with")
    instance = Buildkb.objects.create(keywords=keywords)
    for user in share_with:
        instance.share_with.add(user)
        instance.save()
    return redirect("/")
```

I used class based view instead of function based view.Is there any simple way to access current user details in modelform. I am familiar to access request object with function based view but issue with class based view.
should i go back to function based view  .

Comment: You can access the request object in form_valid with `self.request` and if you want to get the current user, you can just call `self.request.user`.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: I want to access in the modelform(queryset) not in the view,  I want to assign currentuser emailid ,where i mentioned "current user email id" in modelform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the user in your `Build_kbform` and override the `__init__` method of it and then update the queryset as necessary.  Something like this:

```
# forms.py
class Build_kbform(ModelForm):
   # your fields here
   share_with = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelect....)

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      current_user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
      super(Build_kbform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

      if current_user is not None:
         # Modify the queryset here as you see fit
         self.fields['share_with'].queryset = User.objects.filter(
             email_id=currentuser.email_id
         )
```

In your view, you need to override `get_form_kwargs` method and pass the current user.  Something like below:

```
# views.py
class Build_Kb(FormView):

   def get_form_kwargs(self):
      kwargs = super(Build_Kb, self).get_form_kwargs()
      kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
      return kwargs

   def form_valid(self):
      # Your implementation here
      ...
```